# which Xcode is compatible with mono3.0 and lion 10.8

Tags: xcode, mono, monomac

I need to develop a GUI for my MonoMac application. Which Xcode shall I use for cocoa development?

I am using Mono 3.0 and MAC OX Lion 10.8 in VMware on Windows 7 PC.

Comment: Considering Mono 3.0 is still `Release: TBD`, I'd go for the newest possible XCode. I doubt they'd in any way lock a still unreleased Mono version down to an older release of XCode.

Comment: I have tried Xcode 3.2.6 ,but its giving an error ,don't know why ,It terminates at the end of installation.

Comment: I have read somewhere its not good earlier versions were better,I am very new to MAC development

Comment: If you're going to use any Lion or Mountain Lion features in your code, I'd say XCode 4.1 or later are required (although it's not easy to find reference info on versions/SDKs) I'm not 100% sure XCode 3.x is even supported on Mountain Lion, that may be the cause of your error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that you mean MonoDevelop 3.0.x and not Mono 3.0 (they are different things).

If that is the case, any Xcode from 4.2 or newer should work (older versions might work, but have not been tested).

I would suggest that you go with 4.4 or 4.5 as you'll need those if you plan to submit to the AppStore for Mountain Lion.